# "Verbose Dictionary" in C#, 'override new' this[] or implement IDictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, coding-style

All I want is a dictionary which tells me which key it couldn't find, rather than just saying `The given key was not present in the dictionary`.

I briefly considered doing a subclass with `override new this[TKey key]`, but felt it was a bit hacky, so I've gone with implementing the IDictionary interface, and passing everything through directly to an inner Dictionary, with the only additional logic being in the indexer:

```
public TValue this[TKey key]
{
    get
    {
        ThrowIfKeyNotFound(key);
        return _dic[key];
    }
    set
    {
        ThrowIfKeyNotFound(key);
        _dic[key] = value;
    }
}
private void ThrowIfKeyNotFound(TKey key)
{
    if(!_dic.ContainsKey(key))
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Can't find key [" + key + "] in dictionary");
}
```

Is this the right/only way to go? Would newing over the this[] really be that bad?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sounds like a good fit for an extension method:

```
public static class SomeUtilClass {
    public static TValue VerboseGetValue<TKey, TValue>(
        this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> data, TKey key)
    {
        TValue result;
        if (!data.TryGetValue(key, out result)) {
            throw new KeyNotFoundException(
                "Key not found: " + Convert.ToString(key));
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

This will then work on all your existing dictionaries whenever you call `VerboseGetValue`, for example:

```
    var data = new Dictionary<int, string> { { 123, "abc" } };
    Console.WriteLine(data.VerboseGetValue(123));
    Console.WriteLine(data.VerboseGetValue(456));
```

Comment: I'm so glad users #1 and #2 are on the right side of the planet :)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of doing ContainsKey and checking for the presence of the key before touching the underlying dictionary, why not do

```
get {
    try {
        return _dic[key];
    }
    catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException) {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(......);
    }
}
```

That way, you only pay for the extra checking in the failure case - the success case, which is hopefully more common, doesn't have to do an extra dictionary lookup. This is good for get, but set is more difficult since the default behaviour of set is to always work. If you don't want that then you would need to check for the existence of the key first.

Comment: +1 An exception handler is the best way to handle an exceptional condition.  That's what they're for. :)

Comment: @Stewart Unless I'm mistaken, `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary` does not throw an error in the indexer when the key wasn't found, instead it is added silently with the new value. Your approach would still work for the getter though.

Comment: @GeorgesDupéron - You are quite right. This only works in the get case. I will modify the example. For the set case, the additional check is unavoidable.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this, you are going to have to roll your own in one way or another.  But I'm going to question WHY you would want to do this?

Comment: Well, I thought I said why in the question. But rather than getting a mail from the guy doing the setup saying "which value did I get wrong?", I prefer him being able to fix it himself.